# linq-sql insert is ignoring sql server default value for the primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, linq-to-sql

I have a table that the primary key field has a default value of newid() --> that generates a unique id every time a record gets inserted. when I try to insert a record directly in the database from any sql management tool, it works. but when I try to use C# linq-sql insert it gives my the below error:

Cannot insert the value NULL into column '', table ''; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

why is linq ignoring the default value of the field, and is there any alternative way of doing this, given that I don't want the normal sequential int id in the primary key
below is the c# code for the insert:

```
 databaseDataContext db = new databaseDataContext();
        order c = new order();

        c.orderName = "Untitled";
        c.orderStatus = "New";
        db.orders.InsertOnSubmit(c);
        db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Can you show the code please.

Comment: Try updating your model first and then if it's not working, please provide us with a peice of code that throws the exception.

Comment: Yes, since you are using a GUID anyway, generate it in your C# code and assign it your ID field before the insert.

Comment: @dbugger makes a great suggestion - I suspect LINQ-SQL is setting passing the NULL ID to SQL which would prevent SQL from using the default. In any case, generating the key yourself means you don't have to go back to the DB to find out what it was - you can use it in relationships, etc.

Comment: Could you provide the model of your code or table structure

Comment: but how would I ensure uniqueness of the id, and how can I generate something with the same standards as  sql server newid()  method. newid() generates an id which is unique across the world

Comment: a GUID is a Globally Unique Identifier.  It is the same thing that SQL server generates.

Comment: I have done this by setting the UID to a value less than 1 (-1 usually, but in the case that I'm inserting several at once then they decrement as necessary) and then SQL server will auto assign the value.

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion provide by @dbugger is good enough. However, in case you still need it to be generated in SQL, make sure you specify that the ID column (primary key field) has the IsDbGenerated attribute along with the IsPrimaryKey:

```
[Column(IsDbGenerated = true, IsPrimaryKey = true)]
```